# IBOutlet and IBAction in Swift

Tags: swift, iboutlet

I connected a `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` to my button variable from Interface Builder to my View Controller. How do I add an action method to the button in Swift?
This code doesn't seem to work.

```
@IBOutlet var OK: UIButton!
@IBAction func OK(sender: UIButton){}
```

The Objective-C equivalent I found is:

```
@interface Controller
{
    IBOutlet id textField; // links to TextField UI object
}

- (IBAction)doAction:(id)sender; // e.g. called when button pushed
```

Answer (score 13):

When you attach a button to the `viewController` and create an action (`IBAction`) using ctrl-drag, you create a method that looks likes this in Swift (if it doesn't have arguments):

```
@IBAction func buttonAction() {}
```

In Objective-C the same thing will look like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction {}
```

So that means that `@IBAction func OK(sender: UIButton){}` is an action method.

If you want to know about the sender argument, I would recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174015/when-do-we-need-button-to-send-argument-in-swift) SO post.

### Edit:

For what you want to do, I create an `IBOutlet` and an `IBAction`, that way I can change its attributes with the outlet variable, and have the action side of things with the `IBAction`, like what you show above:

```
@IBOutlet var OK: UIButton!
@IBAction func OK(sender: UIButton){}
```

For example, if I want to hide the button, I would put this code in the `viewDidLoad`

```
OK.hidden = true
```

The OK in that code is for the outlet variable, if I wanted to print "You pressed me" to the console when the button is pressed, I would use this code:

```
@IBAction func OK(sender: UIButton){
  println("You pressed me")
}
```

Above I am using the action to print "You pressed me" to the console.

### A few things to note:

When Swift 2.0 gets released `println` will get changed to `print`. Also with you action and outlet, I would suggest giving them differing names, to make it easier to differentiate the two, something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var okOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func okAction(sender: UIButton){}
```

Along with that, you should use camel case when naming variables, constants, functions, etc.

Comment: The solutions mentioned above works if I create a new button of Action type. But I created a button of type outlet and wanted to add an action to it. The reason I created outlet button is that I wanted a variable for the button so that I can set properties for the button variable. Now I also want to add action to it.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it, is control-drag from your button to your viewcontroller and choose action:
[image]

If you have connected your button's action, your code should work just fine.

Comment: Connect the same button twice? One for Outlet and one for Action?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps you can follow-

For `@IBOutlet`

1.Declare Your Interface builder Element property right after class name

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var aTextField : UITextField! ////Your Interface builder Element
```

2.Hook the IB Element From Storyboard.

[image]

For `@IBAction`

1.Write A method inside your class(say `SomeViewController`)

```
@IBAction func anAction(_sender : AnyObject){


}
```

2.Hook the method from Storyboard.

[image]

Hope it might helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add action from your storyboard. See the image.[image]