# How to make a button an IBOutlet and IBAction in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a button which I want to disable when my timer ends in Xcode but to disable to button it needs to be an outlet. However, I need it to be an action because it's an important button.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var count = 0
    var timer = 60
    var highScore = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var highscoreText: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any) {
        count += 1
        output.text = String(count)
    }

    @IBAction func StartButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("updateCounting")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateCounting(){
        if timer > 0 {
        timer -= 1
        timerText.text = String(timer)
        } else {
            buttonOneOutlet.isEnabled = false
            timerText.text = "Time up!"
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + String(count)
            if count > highScore {
                highScore = count
                highscoreText.text = String(count)
            } else {
                highscoreText.text = String(highScore)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Comment: @oscarF123- Please read and follow below links 
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572305/iboutlet-and-ibaction-in-swift
2. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/2/5/from-outlets-to-actions-creating-an-ibaction

Comment: The button can have both an `@IBAction` _and_ an `@IBOutlet`.]

Answer (score 2):

I think you made some confusion between **IBOutlet** and **IBAction**.

Actually here is the difference:

> "You need to specify **IBAction** for *methods* that will be used in
>   Interface Builder and **IBOutlet** for *objects* that will be used in
>   Interface Builder"

([Source - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction))

---

I changed your code a little, starting from `buttonOneOutlet` (**IBOutlet**) and `buttonOne` (**IBAction**).

I added an **IBOutlet** called `buttonOne` and I renamed your **IBActions** like `buttonOneTouched` and `startButtonTouched`. [Here](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming) you can find some documentation about naming conventions in **Swift**.

Moreover I added a variable called `timerObject`, so that you can keep a reference to the running timer and `invalidate()` it later. Otherwise the timer would be running forever.

Here is the updated code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var count = 0
    var timer = 60
    var highScore = 0
    // new timer object declared here
    var timerObject = Timer()

    // new IBOutlet object declared here
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var highscoreText: UILabel!

    // renamed the function to 'buttonOneTouched' (it was 'buttonOne')
    @IBAction func buttonOneTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        count += 1
        output.text = String(count)
    }

    // renamed the function to 'startButtonTouched' (it was 'StartButton')
    @IBAction func startButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        timerObject = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("updateCounting")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateCounting() {
        if timer > 0 {
            timer -= 1
            timerText.text = String(timer)
        } else {
            // added step to invalidate the running timer loop
            timerObject.invalidate()
            // replaced 'buttonOneOutlet' with 'buttonOne'
            buttonOne.isEnabled = false
            timerText.text = "Time up!"
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + String(count)
            if count > highScore {
                highScore = count
                highscoreText.text = String(count)
            } else {
                highscoreText.text = String(highScore)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the same way as you are doing for those Labels

1. Define the button in your ViewController.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonOneOutlet: UIButton!
   ```
2. Set the IBOutlet from your Storyboard to that button, by control drag.

Hope it helps

Comment: But I also need the button to be an action?

Comment: Yes, You can set both the things, IBOutlet will give it identity and IBAction on touch up inside, will give it action.

Comment: but then I get a thread 1: SIGABRT error (aka. Unconnected or something wrong with outlets or actions)

Comment: Try setting the Outlets and Action again for all variables, and may it fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can follow-

For @IBOutlet

1.Declare Your Interface builder Element property just after class name as you already declared for UIlabel

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var btnTest : UIButton! //Your Interface builder Element
```

2.Hook the IB Element From Storyboard
[image]

For @IBAction

1.Write A method inside your class(say SomeViewController)

```
@IBAction func didTapTestBtn(_sender : AnyObject){
//write your code here.
}
```

2.Hook the method from Storyboard.

[image]